# CSS - color direct text only/ do not inherit to other child - classes

Tags: css

I know similar questions have already been asked at least a dozens of times (at least I found a dozen of them), but none of the many answers I found solved my problem.

I just want to color the text which is directly(!) inside these `<h3>` tags:

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h3> I want this green <div class="page-header-button-group">But not this</div></h3>
</div>
```

please note: I cannot change anything in the html. I tried this:

```
.page-header > h3:first-child{
  color:green;
}
```

But it sadly is not doing what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you.

```css
h3 {
  color: green;
}

h3>* {
  /* all children of h3 */
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-header">
  <h3> I want this green
    <div class="page-header-button-group">But not this</div>
  </h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the default value for `color` is not specified and its value is inherited from the parent (see [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_color.asp)). That means, since you specified a color for the `<h3>` and the `<div>` has no other color rules, it will inherit the color from its parent.

The only solution is to reset the color with an extra rule for each child. `h3:first-child > *` (any element which is a direct child of the h3).

```css
.page-header > h3:first-child{
  color:green;
}

.page-header > h3:first-child > * {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-header">
  <h3> I want this green <div class="page-header-button-group">But not this</div></h3>
</div>
```

If this is a common thing in your page, you may also think of a class, e.g.: `.color-default { color: #000; }` (propably adding `!important`). Then you can just define the div as `<div class="default-color">`.